# Populate an oracle collection type using a SYS_REFCURSOR and close the cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor, oracle11g

In my stored procedure, I have a code snippet like this:

```
OPEN p_result FOR
SELECT *
FROM TABLE (CAST ( l_data AS Rpt_mapping_TableType));
COMMIT;
```

`p_result` is an `IN OUT` parameter of type `SYS_REFCURSOR`.`Rpt_mapping_TableType` is a user defined collection type.
So this cursor will just populate the Rpt_mapping_TableType and then the program that calls this proc will read the results from Rpt_mapping_TableType.
My question is what is the use of `COMMIT` in this snippet? The code author says it is a way of closing the cursor. Is it right?  My other question is if I just want to populate the collection , do I even need to do `OPEN p_result FOR`. After all I am not reading anything from the cursor so :

```
SELECT *  FROM TABLE (CAST ( l_data AS Rpt_mapping_TableType));
```

should suffice.

No?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A commit will not close a cursor.  If it did, then your code wouldn't work.  (Although it could unlock rows from a `FOR UPDATE`, causing other problems.)  Here's an example of a commit not closing a cursor:

```
SQL> variable test refcursor
SQL> begin
  2  open :test for select 1 from dual;
  3  end;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> print test;

         1
----------
         1

SQL>
```

If you just want to populate a collection, you're probably better off using something like `SELECT ... BULK COLLECT INTO ...` instead.  (And possibly using a `LIMIT`.)  The keyword `CURSOR` is frequently over-used.  Unless you're passing data to another program, implicit cursors and bulk collects are usually much simpler and faster.